# Fetch entry using PHP

Tags: channel-entries-api

Is there a way to get an entry using only PHP? I've looked at the developer API, http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/api/api_channel_entries.html, but there doesn't seem to be a way to fetch an entry.

I'd like to do this:

```
$entry = ee()->api_channel_entries->get_entry($entry_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use the Bones plugin and get data over the ACT (Action) APIs, such as:

`?ACT=40&url_title=$sSlug`

Or:

`?ACT=40&entry_id=$nEntryID`

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: there is no API for this.

Longer answer: there is no API, but... You could either check out [ObjectiveHTML's Channel Data library](https://github.com/objectivehtml/Channel-Data). You could also try and utilize the Channel module. However, that path is completely undocumented, so if you decide to go that route, tread lightly.